# SSRS PDF Export taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created an SSRS matrix report. When i see the report in the preview it shows me 550 pages. But when i export the matrix report to PDF, it takes infinity to export it into PDF. I have tried using different ways to reduce the number of pages, also tried to minimize the use of expressions and formatting but still the report is taking too long to export. Even after 1 hour of rendering, i had to cancel the export because it was not coming back.

Could anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is that you need to simplify your report.  Why on earth do you need hundreds of pages?

When viewing SSRS reports in Visual Studio, Report Builder or via Report Manager, only the current page is rendered and none of the extra work required to generate a several hundred page PDF.  This is what is taking the time.